# Statistical Network Usage Tools

Tags: networking, server, 12.04, statistical

I am looking for applications that can do an statistical network usage. I will be putting up a server with squid proxy and would like to know of a program that can show me what pages are visited more, what users use more bandwidth and any other stats that can be found while using the server for internet access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For squid I am using sqstat. Here is the [link for the product](http://samm.kiev.ua/sqstat/) Also there is another tool call [Sarg](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/sarg.php)

Comment: Sarg did it for me. Very nice analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the option "emulate http log" on it squid it will create log files that looks just like an Apache log file.

Then you can use any tool that supports parsing and presenting logs for web servers.

There are quite a few. Personally i have had success with AWStats